# Make homepage the newest post of a custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types

I am using the plugin "Custom Post Types" to create an issue based magazine, where one of my types is "Covers." There will be one of these posts for each issue and will include the cover art and an list of articles in the issue. My question is, how can I make the main page default to display a single view of the newest post of this type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a `front-page.php` file in the theme and query for the latest post of your post type.

```
$args = array(
  'post_type' => 'yourtypename',
  'posts_per_page' => 1,
  'ignore_sticky_posts' => true,
  'post_status' => 'publish',
}
$latest = new WP_Query($args);
if ($latest->have_posts()) {
  while ($latest->have_posts()) {
    $latest->the_post();
    the_title();
    // etc
  }
}
```

See the [Template Hierarchy](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy) for information about files that are "automagically" loaded..

Comment: You've got an extra `,` at `'posts_per_page', => 1,`, which I suspect will cause problems.